# uptime command gives weird results in a docker image

Tags: docker, uptime

If I run a docker image and call `uptime`, I always get a longer value than the real one.

```
docker run -it 1d2dfb3a35ab
root@7efb3e947f73:/# uptime
 23:41:57 up 16 min,  0 users,  load average: 0.06, 0.02, 0.00
```

It hasn't been running for 16 minutes, not even 16 seconds. =:-O

Is this a known issue or what?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The displayed uptime is that of the host. The kernel does not track uptime for individual containers in this way (though Docker does).

Answer (score 27):

The first process start time could be used as container start time:

```
stat /proc/1/cmdline
```

`/proc/1/cmdline` is a virtual file in the procfs, whose creation date is the same as the container creation date. The stat command shows its filesystem-level attributes, its creation date between them.

Comment: Good solution, I understand it pretty well, but somebody hasn't. Maybe 1-2 explaining sentence could improve it a lot.

Comment: ...around so should be already okay. Here is an upvote for the excellent, non-trivial solution!

Comment: Good idea! When I `docker exec` into a container `stat /proc/1/cmdline` does not give me the time the container was started but the the time I run `docker exec`. But doing `stat /proc/1/` seems to give the container start time.

Comment: I get Feb 25 2019, should have been Oct 04 2018 according to docker. I've seen people swear by using the modified dates in /proc/$PID/ to figure out when a process was started, but I haven't seen it work on any of my systems. The contents of /proc is generally generated on the fly by the kernel.

Comment: `ps -o etime= -p 1` seems to work every time.